# signtool.exe runs slowly under different user account

Tags: .net, performance, signtool

We use signtool.exe to sign a set of managed assemblies (from a command prompt, we run signtool.exe in a trivial .bat file for-loop, applying a certificate from a pfx file)

- When run under a domain administrator's account, it runs in under 1 minute.
- When run under a local user account, it takes 37 minutes!

The setup and conditions (aside from the login account used) are identical in both cases.

Needless to say, our build server is running using the "wrong" account!

Can anyone think of any user-account settings that might influence the speed of signtool.exe so significantly? Does it need to interact with any external services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a momment of inspiration, I've solved the problem. If anyone else comes across this, it was because of our **proxy server**.

The admin account had exclusions so that local addresses would not be resolved through the proxy server, but the build account did not have the exclusions, so signtool was needlessly round-tripping via our proxy (thousands of miles away, and hence very slow).

I don't know why signtool needs to ping the internet when signing a local file using a local pfx file with timestamping disabled, but adding the local proxy exclusions fixed it.

Comment: Because signtool needs to check CRL online to verify if the signing cert has been revoked or not

Comment: Would that check really cause it to take that long to run? Why wouldn't the domain administrator's account have to do the same check?

Comment: patrickvacek: In this case I think it was more than just a slow connection - it was probably failing because it was not passing the required authentication details to our proxy server. This was probably causing the process to lock up until it timed out, and then presumably it kept re-trying, so it basically locked up the build process for over half an hour simply waiting for replies it never received. The admin account was fast because it was able to communicate with the certificate authority's server.

Comment: I also faced similar issue: In my case, server is restricted the incoming and outgoing access and allows very few access. unblocking the restricted access in my server helped to solve the problem.